# Multiple filters not working elasticsearch rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

In my Invoice Model i have 3 term filters defined in 3 separate methods. The query works fine but at a time only filter is applied on the query. 
If i change the order of the filters then only the top filter is applied remaining two filters are ignored.

Following is the code of model:

```
Invoice.search(self.search_options(options, qry))

def self.search_options(options, qry)
  [query(qry),
   status_filter(options[:status]),
   state_filter(options[:invoice_state]),
   office_filter(options[:current_office_id]),
   aggregates
  ].compact.reduce(:merge)
end

def self.status_filter(status)
  {filter: {term: {invoice_status: status}}}
end

def self.state_filter(state)     
  {filter: {term: {state: state}}}
end

def self.office_filter(current_office_id)
  {filter: {term: {office_id: current_office_id}}}
end
```

How can i apply all the 3 filters at a time ?

Comment: Can you share equivalent Query DSL  on behalf of rails code?

Comment: {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}},{"term":{"invoice.office_id":"someid"}},{"term":{"invoice.invoice_status":"active"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[],"facets":{}}

Comment: While copy your query in sense I found two error in query dsl. I have tried similar query its works for me. [Demo Example](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/1c30b06451910e025216f9cb3a03670c3fd9a5e4)

Comment: @Roopendra Is multiple filters working fine for you ?

Comment: Yeah Multiple filter should work . Please refer my query which i share in qbox.

Comment: I tried the query it works but it still not working in my rails code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75681/discussion-between-roopendra-and-arif).